# SEVIS completed (graduated) may be terminated

Tags: usa, canada, f1-visas

I recently graduated with a bachelors degree in September 24,2018 . I didn't know I had a grace period of 60 days to either apply for opt or transfer to a different college. (But I had been applying to colleges for masters for Spring). The colleges I applied had their semesters running, so maybe they delayed my application review.

I recently got acceptance from 2 colleges, went back to previous college for transfer only to know that my SEVIS was automatically completed (exceeding the grace period) . I'm filing for reinstatement in a week . Its not been more than 5 months . Since I have only 2 options left i.e travel outside and return 2. reinstatement. 
I am thinking of using both .

So the question is: will I be able to apply to Canada as a tourist (for short trip) or even as student (if possible)? What are my chances of getting a visa? (forger visa im worried about applying too  , since Canada and US share the status , Canadian authorities will know my SEVIS is completed and I have few months of unlawful presence). Are there any chances?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: My advice is that you go home and proceed from there. Your Canadian visa application will be denied. Similar happened to me in 2009. The Canadians always check your status in USA

Comment: If you are filing for reinstatement, my advice is to **not depart the USA** unless advised by an immigration lawyer, or your application fails. For more, I suggest our sister site [expatriates.se] where you may be able to get a proper answer to this question, or better yet, contact an immigration lawyer if possible.